# Inventory Database in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have our company inventory stored in a google sheet.
A very basic setup with headers such as part# and quantity.
As of right now, we use AppSheets. 
When someone takes an item it records the part# and quantity in a feed on a seperate google sheet.

Is it possible with google sheets for the feed to automatically make the changes to the inventory database?
So the program would reference the part# on the feed and make changes to that part# on the database sheet.
Or is that way above the capability of sheets and I should be looking into SQL for that functionality?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Google Apps Script can edit Spreadsheets pretty much like a user can with a few minor exceptions. I suggest checking out some of the [guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) to get into it.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach yes i did look into that but was not sure if there were any built in functions. seems as if that is the route i must head in. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to control stock without scripts then you could connect your inventory sheet to your sales sheet using `sumif`.

Simply summing *all* the sales and subtracting from the current stock level would not work correctly so you could record the date or date & time when your stock is counted for each part and then only count and subtract the sales after that date.

[image]

The `sumif` is summing if the part number in column A on the Sales sheet matches the inventory part and the sales date in column C on the Sales sheet is greater than or equal to the stock take date.

I added some conditional formatting to highlight a low stock level.

link the the example Google sheet.

View:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IhsUlVo57gZYnRisE11QQCWSWqazGDy9RUiWmiUmZ8/view?usp=sharing

Copy:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IhsUlVo57gZYnRisE11QQCWSWqazGDy9RUiWmiUmZ8/copy?usp=sharing